# Problema declarando un HashMap con genéricos - ( unexpected type required:reference, found long)

Tags: java, clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No sé si se aprecia la imagen, tengo esta línea de código que me da error:

HashMap agenda = new HashMap();

Tengo importado el java.util.*; y java.io.*;

Al poner el cursor encima de la línea de código sale el cuadro
unexpected type
Required: reference
found: long

No logro entender qué falta, qué me estoy brincando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que usar:

```
HashMap<String, Long> agenda = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

En genéricos se usan las clases que representan los primitivos, no los primitivos mismos.

- short - Short
- int - Integer
- long - Long
- float - Float
- double - Double
- char - Character
- byte - Byte
- boolean - Boolean

String es un caso especial en que las variables siempre se declaran con la clase `String`.

Answer (score 0):

En java estan los datos primitivos y los de referencia (Objectos)

cada tipo primitivo tiene una clase de Envoltorio (Wrapper Class) la cual recibe un tipo primitivo {byte,short,int,float,double,long,boolean,char
}  y retorna un objecto

Lista de los primitivos y su clase de envoltorio :

- byte -> Byte
- short -> Short
- int -> Integer
- float -> Float
- double -> Double
- long -> Long
- boolean -> Boolean
- char -> Character

tu Map quedaria asi :

```
//Al especificar el tipo de dato en la declaracion No es necesario volverlo a especificar en la instanciacion. 
Map<String,Long> agenda = new HashMap<>();
```

Espero te sirva

Saludos